# How can I force the user of a library template to explicitly tag particular template parameters as acceptable (but only sometimes)?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a family of classes in a library that can be "installed" in another class, either as a single member or as an array, dependent on the application.  The arrays are indexed with an integer or enum type, dependent on the application (`void` is used when an array is not meaningful).  The installable class itself has no control over the indexing; the application using the class defines the index.

However, I imagine that unwanted specialziations could be created by a typo and compile OK.

I want to constrain the indexing types to only the ones intended for the application, by making the client signal back to the library which associations are OK.  I couldn't see a pure template metaprogramming approach, so I thought I'd exploit ODR and explicit specialization of class members.

```
namespace foo {

    template <class P, class ROLE>
    struct association
    {
        static_assert(std::is_enum_v<ROLE>||std::is_integral_v<ROLE>);
        static const bool allowed();
    };

    
    template <class T>
    class bar final
    {
    public:
        bar() = default;
        ~bar() = default;
    };

    void do_something() {}

    template <class I, class ROLE>
    void install(I &&i, ROLE r)
    {
       if (association<std::decay_t<I>, ROLE>::allowed()) do_something();
    }

    template <class I>
    void install(I &&i)
    {
       if (association<std::decay_t<I>, void>::allowed()) do_something();
    }
}
```

With the following sample use:

```
// declare the indexing type
enum myindex { min=0, max=3 };

int main() {
    foo::bar<int> foobar;
    foo::install(foobar, myindex::min);
    return 0;
}
```

There should be a linker error unless we also add

```
// add a definiton to make the association with myindex OK
template <> const bool foo::association<bar<int>, myindex>::allowed() { return true; }
```

In the full code, the value of "allowed" doesn't matter, only the existence of a definition does.

It's a pretty cryptic way of saying "this association is OK", but it works.  At least, if you fully specialize `association`. But this is where the "sometimes" comes in: Some of the templates are supposed to work with any indexing type. It's a pain to make the library user write out specializations for these templates.  But the following

```
template <class T, class ROLE> const bool foo::association<foo::bar<T>, ROLE>::allowed () { return true; }
```

is a compiler error, because it's not a full specialization.

Is there a way to fully define `association::allowed()` for all combinations of `bar` specializations with any `ROLE`,  but force the user to define it for other templates?

If not, is there a better approach that accomplishes this goal? (Hopefull, something that can be used with `static_assert` because what I have now is charitably called 'clunky').

Remember, `myindex` cannot be rolled into the library. (I'm sticking to C++17 for the time being).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case seems like a good place for template variables. One of their use is to make them a kind of a map - which in this case would greatly increase readability of the client code and move everything to compile-time. If you just want to break compilation the following should be fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// make_association is a variable template which works as a compile-time map
// default value is false_type = no relation
template <typename I,typename ROLE>
constexpr std::false_type make_association;

// isAssociated used as a compile-time "function"
template <typename I, typename R>
using isAssociated = decltype(make_association<std::decay_t<I>,std::decay_t<R>>);

template <typename I, typename ROLE>
void install( I &&i, ROLE r)
{
  static_assert(isAssociated<I,ROLE>(), "make_association<I, ROLE> not registered");
  static_assert(std::is_enum_v<ROLE> || std::is_integral_v<ROLE> );
  std::cout<<"Entered install( I &&, ROLE r)"<<std::endl;
}

template <typename I>
void install( I &&i)
{
  static_assert(isAssociated<I,void>(), "make_association<I, void> not registered");
  std::cout<<"Entered install( I &&)"<<std::endl;
}

enum WrongIndexT { ok = 1};
enum IndexT { min=0, max=3 };
class ObjT final {};

// a class for which any index works
template <class T> class Any final {};
template <class T, class Index>
constexpr std::true_type make_association<Any<T>, Index>;

// here the relations are set using variable template specialization;
template<> constexpr std::true_type make_association<ObjT, IndexT>;
template<> constexpr std::true_type make_association<ObjT, void>;

int main() {
  ObjT f1,f2,f3;
  install(f1, IndexT::min);
  install(f2);
  install(Any<int>{}, WrongIndexT::ok); // OK 
  install(f1, WrongIndexT::ok); // compilation error
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. To complete your answer, I added a way to make a given template work for any index (I tested it and it works).